# How to call OpenCSV library CSVReader(Reader in, char x) in Groovy?

Tags: java, csv

I have having trouble calling OpenCSV library CSVReader(Reader in, char x) in Groovy?  The problem is that Groovy thinks of single-quoted literals as a String rather than a character and the constructor requires a character.

Therefore, this doesn't work:

```
reader = new CSVReader( new FileReader( tFile ), ',' )
```

I tried this and it didn't work either:

```
reader = new CSVReader( new FileReader( tFile ), String.toCharacter(",").charValue() )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a feature of Groovy, you need to cast the literal to char like this:

```
reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(tFile), (char) ',')
```

or like this:

```
reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(tFile), ',' as char)
```

You can even use double quotes. See this [issue ticket](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-1590)